# Excel Compare Function / Software

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a report that shows different names in column A. I want to compare the values from COL B for each country in column A. In COL C, I would like to return the maximum value from COL B for that country. This is an example of what I'd like:

```
          COL A     COL B          COL C (OUTPUT RESULT REQUIRED) 
Row 1     USA        $3             -    
Row 2     USA        $7             $7 
Row 3     Italy      $1             $1
Row 4     France     $2             -
Row 5     France     $9             $9
Row 6     France     $4             -
```

I am using Excel 2016.

How can I do this with a function?

Comment: What (functions) have you tried?.

Comment: countif and maxifs but I might not be doing it correct

Comment: Why the duplicate question on different sites? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101933/compare-two-cells-and-return-highest-value-from-third-cells/43101983#43101983

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formula that will do the trick.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,A1,$B$1:$B$6,">"&B1)=0,B1,"-")
```

This uses `COUNTIFS` to count the rows for each country that have a greater value than the current row. Only the max row(s) will return the value.

Comment: FWIW: there is not detriment to using full column references with COUNIFS():  `=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,A1,$B:$B,">"&B1)=0,B1,"-")`

Comment: @Excellll: This formula works great. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Nomi Welcome to Super User! If this answer resolved your problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. This lets other users know that the solution works and that you have resolved your problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. this formula:
`=IF(AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,B:B)>B2,"-",B2)`

[image]

Comment: Simply beauty. Thanks for all your help. I give you 5 Stars

Comment: Though this will return false positives, change the 4 in France to 8 and it will return 8 as well as the 9.

Comment: Yes, as I am doing it I realize this thing. What if I just want to display only one hieghest value for each country.

Comment: @Nomi you still have not responded to my Edit #2 on Stack Overflow, Also the best formula is the one by Excellll given on this question.

Comment: @Scott: I just responded